# Tomcat 7 Log produces an error when a simple JSF application is running

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I followed this guide (http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_JSF_applications) and I've created a simple Hello world application using JSF.
It runs fine and it produces a `http://localhost:8080/index.faces` page that displays the phrase 'Hello world'.
The problem is that Tomcat 7 log shows a serious error.
Here is what it says :

> Jan 31, 2013 5:58:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with
>   path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page
>   /index.jsp at line 14
>
> 11:   Simple jsp page 12:    13: 
>   14:    15:        16:
>    17:
>
> Stacktrace:] with root cause java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find
>   FacesContext  at
>   javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getFacesContext(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1855)
>     at
>   javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1672)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(index_jsp.java:111)
>     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:83)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> Jan 31, 2013 5:58:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log

I am new to JSF so I can't understand what this error means.
Any ideas?
Than you.

PS : (I am running mountain lion and I am using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception can be ignored, it happens during some validation, when `index.jsp` page is requested instead of `index.faces`.

If you refresh `index.faces` in the browser, you will not see any more errors, if you open `index.jsp`, you will see the second copy of the same error in Tomcat log.

`index.jsp` is the default page, so you will get this error if `http://localhost:8080` is requested.

The problem can be fixed by adding the following in `web.xml` under `web-app`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.faces</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This way `index.jsp` will not be accessed when you open just `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: How can I access Tomcat 7 homepage? `http://localhost:8080` redirects me now at the index.faces page.

Comment: Change context of the artifact in the deployment tab so that your application is deployed under different context instead of ROOT, then you should be able to access the default ROOT context.